# sql query with WHERE

Tags: android, sql, database, where-clause

i am trying to implement a detabase query using WHERE, and really just wondering how to implement it? the code i have here gives me an error ;/ thnánk you!

```
        public Cursor fetchAllCatagoryForSign(String sign) {
        String signSelect="";
        if(sign!=null){
            signSelect=" WHERE " + CATAGORY_SIGN + "=" + sign;
        }
        return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT " + CATAGORY_ID + "," +
                " " + CATAGORY_NAME +  "," +
                " " + CATAGORY_SIGN + " FROM "
                + CATAGORY_TABLE + signSelect + 
                " ORDER BY " + CATAGORY_NAME + " DESC", null);
    }
```

Comment: FFS: Why do people never include the error in their questions?

Comment: And show what the final SQL statement looks like before executing

Comment: i did not because i have never used a where-cluase so thought it was just that i did totally wrong when writing it. i will post logcat now

Answer (score 0):

If sign is a string related to a TEXTual (e.g. varchar) column, you would need quotes around it in most DBMS.

```
public Cursor fetchAllCatagoryForSign(String sign) {
    String signSelect="";
    if(sign!=null){
        signSelect=" WHERE " + CATAGORY_SIGN + "='" + sign.Replace("'","''") + "'";
    }
    return mDb.rawQuery("SELECT " + CATAGORY_ID + "," +
            " " + CATAGORY_NAME +  "," +
            " " + CATAGORY_SIGN + " FROM "
            + CATAGORY_TABLE + signSelect + 
            " ORDER BY " + CATAGORY_NAME + " DESC", null);
}
```

@updated following GolezTrol's note

If category sign comes from a user from the world at large, this pieces of code would be open to SQL injection, in which case, you would want to protect the "sign" variable using .Replace as shown in the code.

Comment: Yes, only you will probably want to escape quotes in the query too. Someone searching for `Don't` will break the query. Someone searching for `screwed'; drop database; --` will break a lot more. :)

Comment: @GolezTrol - good point. I was expecting it to be from some system list of category signs but better to protect nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide your error. You could try to switch to:

```
String.format(" WHERE %s = '%s'", CATEGORY_SIGN, sign);

String.format("SELECT %s, %s, %s, %s FROM %s %s ORDER BY %s DESC, null, CATEGORY_ID, CATEGORY_NAME, CATEGORY_SIGN, CATEGORY_TABLE, signSelect, CATEGORY_NAME);
```

I think this is a bit cleaner, even though you could format it better in your IDE.